# iOS - Trying to implement animating clock: Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints runtime error -noob level 99

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, animated

I admit I'm in over my head here, but I think I'm missing something simple.

I found this sweet clock on github but it's not packaged to be includable, and I don't understand the runtime error about constraints enough to properly implement this code. I love this clock though, so if anybody can help I would love to include it in my app!

The clock:
https://github.com/DuncanMC/ClockAnimation

What I did:

-started a new single view Xcode project
-copied (drag and dropped) the clock hands images out of Images.xcassets into this Images.xcassets in my project
-copied the relevant classes and view controller code

I get this error at runtime:

```
Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 

(
    "<NSIBPrototypingLayoutConstraint:0x8c31fb0 'IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame' H:[UIImageView:0x8c2bde0(22)]>",
    "<NSIBPrototypingLayoutConstraint:0x8c31fe0 'IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame' V:[UIImageView:0x8c2bde0(250)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSIBPrototypingLayoutConstraint:0x8c31fe0 'IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame' V:[UIImageView:0x8c2bde0(250)]>

Break on objc_exception_throw to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2014-06-11 14:34:36.537 Project Manager[1739:70b] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSIBPrototypingLayoutConstraint:0x8c32070 'IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame' H:[UIImageView:0x8c2fa00(22)]>",
    "<NSIBPrototypingLayoutConstraint:0x8c320a0 'IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame' V:[UIImageView:0x8c2fa00(250)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSIBPrototypingLayoutConstraint:0x8c320a0 'IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame' V:[UIImageView:0x8c2fa00(250)]>

Break on objc_exception_throw to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2014-06-11 14:34:36.555 Project Manager[1739:70b] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSIBPrototypingLayoutConstraint:0x8c32200 'IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame' H:[UIImageView:0x8c0d210(22)]>",
    "<NSIBPrototypingLayoutConstraint:0x8c32230 'IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame' V:[UIImageView:0x8c0d210(250)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSIBPrototypingLayoutConstraint:0x8c32230 'IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame' V:[UIImageView:0x8c0d210(250)]>

Break on objc_exception_throw to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

Comment: Have you imported the Storyboard?

Comment: Because if the problem are constraints there could be something wrong with the nib.

Answer (score 1):

Turn off auto layout in the view's file inspector ! It should work. [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kiqdn.png)

Answer (score 0):

If the storyboard / nib itself is giving you any layout warnings / errors whatever, fix them! Do not attempt to run until all warnings / errors are gone.

Otherwise, either turn off auto layout or give your views meaningful constraints - and again, you will then need to keep applying constraints until all warnings/errors are gone.